# Working with git in local machine to upload

Tags: git

I am very new with `git`version control.
I have the project in a directory. I have done these steps:

- Navigated to the project directory.
- `git init`
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "First commit"`

And tried to upload to guthub using

```
git add remote origin https://github.com/userName/repo.git
```

but it gives

> fatal: pathspec 'remote' did not match any files

Comment: [This](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) may help!!!

Comment: It’s `git remote add` not `git add remote`. And yes, read the Git book as Praveen suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax to add remote is wrong. The correct syntax is `git remote add origin {remote_upstream_name}` according to which you have to use

`git remote add origin https://github.com/userName/repo.git`.

After you execute this command, you will have origin as remote. You can verify this by executing `git remote -v` which should display your origin name along with url as:

```
# Verify new remote
origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)
```

Then you can push your changes to the remote origin using following command.

`git push -u origin master`

Here `-u` will keep your current branch in sync with your remote branch so from next time you can just do `git push` and it will push your changes to the remote branch. It also depends on other configs so you have to know about `git push` see [git-push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

Hope this clears your confusions. Let us know if this helps you or not.

Comment: i can verify the new remote but how would i upload by project to that .git.

Comment: i got these two errors `error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs`

Comment: What do you get when you execute `git remote -v` ?